# I can't escape square brackets for syntax matching

Tags: syntax-highlighting, neovim

I have the following code in my ini.vim:

```
augroup HiParens
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax c :syn match Parens /[(){}]/
    autocmd Syntax c :syn match Bracks /[\[\]]/
augroup End
```

And highlighting is done in ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/c.vim

```
hi Parens ctermfg=XXX
hi Bracks ctermfg=XXX
```

The first match `/[(){}]/` works as expected.
The second seem to do nothing. 
Yet this is the way I understand the help page I am supposed to do this.
I found somewhere else here on SE a suggestion about doing exactly this escaping but can't find the link anymore. 
I'm a bit surprised, for I would think such escaping would be pretty logical and I also don't get any Errors when loading a C file.
Does anybody know what I did wrong? Must be a stupid detail failure on my end...

Comment: What happens if you add `containedin=ALL` to the Bracks statement?

Comment: Hi Ralf, I'm not sure how to use that. I tried ... match Bracks containedin=ALL /[\[\]]/ and ... match Bracks /[\[\]]/ containedin=ALL. Neither works unfortunately.

Comment: `/[\[\]]/` actually matches \, `[`, and `]`.   The pattern you want is `/[[\]]/`, i.e. only `]` needs to be escaped inside a collection.

Comment: Ok, I can see some rationale in that. Unfortunately it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me in Vim (8.1.2044).

Anyway, I would recommend to create the file `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/c.vim` to extend the C highlighting.

```
syn match Parens /[(){}]/
syn match Bracks /[[\]]/

hi Parens term=underline ctermfg=11 guifg=Yellow
hi Bracks term=underline ctermfg=11 guifg=Yellow
```

Adjust `hi ...` to your liking.

---

For working with syntax and highlighting I have the following in my vimrc:

```
command SynID  echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

Move the cursor to the place you want to inspect (e.g. a bracket) and execute `:SynID`. It will print the name of the syntax item under the cursor.
If it prints nothing, your `syntax match...` does not work. If it prints the correct name, but is not higlighted, there is a problem with the `hi ...` statement. If it prints a different name, you might want to look at `:help :syn-contains`, `:help :syn-contained` and `:help :syn-containedin`.

Comment: Cool, simply using ~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/c.vim did the trick. I don't know why it wouldn't in ini.vim but this is way better for organization anyway. Thanks a lot! Also this inspector thingy is quite handy. Still a long way to go in learning VimL.